# Isomorphism between finitely generated semigroups

Tags: reference-request, semigroups, semigroup-homomorphism

May I ask you to make light on the following point. I know that there maybe certain conditions of the type of two semigroups. I am simply looking articles or a nice hint-answer just for sure:

> Does any isomorphism map generators to generators when we consider finitely generated semigroups?

I wonder what would it be if they are finitely presented?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: I don’t get it. Any isomorphism maps generating sets to generating sets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f:S \to T$ be a semigroup isomorphism. Then $E$ is a generating set for $S$ if, and only if, $f(E)$ is a generating set for $T$. No need for $S$ to be finitely generated or finitely presented.

Comment: For thesake of completeness, here’s a proof for this. Let $S$ and $S'$ be semigroups and $T ⊆ S$ and let $φ \colon S → S'$ be a map of semigroups. Then for any semigroup $S'' ⊆ S'$

$$⟨φ(T)⟩ ⊆ S'' ⇔ φ(T) ⊆ S'' ⇔ T ⊆ φ^{-1}(S'') ⇔ ⟨T⟩ ⊆ φ^{-1}(S'') ⇔ φ(⟨T⟩) ⊆ S''$$

Since the image of a semigroup under any homomorphism of semigroups is again a semigroup, taking $S'' = ⟨φ(T)⟩$ and $S'' = φ(⟨T⟩)$ respectively, we see that $⟨φ(T)⟩ = φ(⟨T⟩)$.

Comment: Thanks Jean-E for the answer. I wanted to be sure of it. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: May I ask you to refer me to the right side? I found less abouton the web: are there conditions in which we can have isomorphism between to finite semigroups? I know that if it exists, then they have same cardinals and also they have to behave similarly. But checking when you work on semigroups is not easy than when you work on groups. Regards.

Comment: @resident-dementor Your question is to general for me to answer. Perhaps you should try to elaborate it, for instance by giving examples of finite semigroups you would like to compare.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Dear Jane-E, sorry for the delay and thanks for the last comment. I considered two finitely generated semigroups. For ex. two transformation semigroups can be generated by GAP easily. Now, I am trying to make a isomorphism between them. At this ppint, I don't know if I can make it as an iso.? That's why I was converted to my last comment. Regards.